# remove array element with non numeric key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects where the key is an md5 string and the value is an object
[0315778255cca8d2f773642ad1d3678f] = {a:12,b:34}. I need to remove array elements based on their key, i tried splice but failed cause i suppose the keys are non numeric. 
I also tried to splice by position, but that failed to, and even delete the element but we all know that it is not ideal.

I could change my implemantation from array to object but that too will have the same problems more or less i suppose.

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` is indeed about the array indexes (as the numeric properties of arrays are called), not about other properties.

To remove a property from an object (including an array), use [`delete`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1):

```
delete theArray['0315778255cca8d2f773642ad1d3678f'];
```

Despite its similarity to "delete" in other languages, `delete` in JavaScript has nothing (directly) to do with memory management; all it does is remove a property from an object (entirely; it doesn't just set the property's value to `undefined` or something).

Side note: If you're *only* using non-numeric properties, you probably don't want an array at all. The only reason for using JavaScript's `Array` type is if you need the special handling it gives properties whose names are all digits, the magic `length` (which only relates to the numeric properties), and the stuff from `Array.prototype` — none of which does anything with other, non-index properties.

---

Re your comment below:

> delete leaves an undefined in the elements place. i need to get rid of it completely

No, `delete` removes the property, entirely. It does not leave `undefined` in its place. You might be thinking it does because any time you try to retrieve a property from an object that doesn't exist, you get back `undefined`. E.g.:

```
var obj = {};            // Object with no "foo" property at all
var x = obj.foo;
console.log("x = " + x); // "x = undefined"
```

You can prove that the property really is removed by using `hasOwnProperty` or `in`:

```
var obj = {};
console.log('foo' in obj);              // "false"
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "false"
```

`in` will check the object and its prototype chain; `hasOwnProperty` just checks the object itself.

Coming back to `delete`:

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "false"
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "true"
delete obj.foo;
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "false"
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "true"
delete obj['foo'];
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // "false"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/abiler) | [source](http://jsbin.com/abiler/edit)

Note that both `delete obj.foo;` and `delete obj['foo'];` work if `foo` is a valid identifier. But for properties whose names aren't valid identifiers (like your md5 sums), you have to use the bracketed form with the string as I showed above (`delete theArray['0315778255cca8d2f773642ad1d3678f'];`).

Comment: delete leaves an undefined in the elements place. i need to get rid of it completely

Comment: @mbouclas: No, it doesn't. I've added to the answer to explain what you're seeing.